# deployment descriptor mapping syntax

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a servlet as

```
TestServlet.java

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{
```

In the `web.xml` I add the following for mapping

```
<web-app>
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-path>TestServlet</servlet-path>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

However, on running `TestServlet.java` it still gives the `resource not found error`

Comment: What do you mean _on running_? Does your `TestServlet` class belong to some package?

Comment: It is in the default Package. On running would mean when I do a ' Run As ' and ' Run on Server ', I get a ' resource not found ' error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
<servlet-path>TestServlet</servlet-path>
```

should be

```
<servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class>
```

Otherwise your deployment descriptor is invalid.

You should probably specify a web app version in your web.xml. [Here are some templates.](http://dominikdorn.com/2010/03/web-xml-web-fragment-xml-2-3-2-4-2-5-3-0/)

---

Also, you don't run a `Servlet`. What you do is deploy your web application in Tomcat's `webapps` folder and start Tomcat. Tomcat acts as a server. Your `Servlet` acts as a handler for some URL.